# No such module 'SwiftyJSON'

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swifty-json

I have been facing this issue since days now... i have a framework in my workspace which somehow does not seem to like SwiftyJSON module and throws an error "No such module SwiftyJSON"

My pod file looks something like this

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'dummyprojectName' do 
    pod 'socket.IO', '~> 0.5'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git =>'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

Hope to find some help soon :)

Answer (score 6):

Try clearing your project (Cmd + K). Then cmd + B for build. Also make sure you use xcworkspace file (not xcodeproj).

Comment: Thanks, for me opening the xcworkspace file was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to XCode 7.3 and Swift 2.2. That might help resolve the issue. I had a similar issue with Alamofire

Comment: Tried this too.. not working! thanks for the reply though :)